# Find value of a dynamic control from a formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data

I have created a dynamically created FromView which contains a list of user details.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="DetailsPanel" runat="server" CssClass="formview">
            <br />
            <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="DetailsDataSource" RenderOuterTable="false" 
                OnPreRender="FormView1_PreRender" OnModeChanging="FormView1_ModeChanging" OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated"
                OnItemInserted="FormView1_ItemInserted" OnItemDeleted="FormView1_ItemDeleted" OnItemCommand="FormView1_ItemCommand">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table id="detailsTable" class="DDDetailsTable" cellpadding="6" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Order No</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="OrderNo" runat="server" DataField="OrderNo" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">User ID</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="UserID" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Display Name</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DisplayName" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Email Address</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="EmailAddress" runat="server" DataField="EmailAddress" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Project Code</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ProjectCode" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Event Description</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="EventDesc" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Delivery Date</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DeliveryDate" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Date Ordered</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DateOrdered" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Site</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Site" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Time</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Time" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Time Room is Available</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl1" runat="server" DataField="TimeRoomAvailable" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Time Room to be Cleared</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl2" runat="server" DataField="TimeCleared" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Location</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Location" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Additional Information</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="AdditionalInfo" DataField="AdditionalInfo" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Item Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="ItemCosts" DataField="ItemCosts" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">AdditionalCosts</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="AdditionalCosts" DataField="AdditionalCosts" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Total Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="TotalCosts" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">More Information Required</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="MoreInformationRequired" UIHint="MultilineText" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Reason Rejected</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ReasonRejected" UIHint="MultilineText" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Order Progress</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="OrderProgress" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Imported Into Dream</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ImportedIntoDream" /></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr class="td">
                       <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
                                OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                 <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Order No</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="OrderNo" runat="server" DataField="OrderNo" Mode="ReadOnly"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">User ID</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="UserID" Mode="ReadOnly"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Display Name</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DisplayName" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Email Address</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="EmailAddress" ID="Email"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Project Code</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ProjectCode" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Event Description</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="EventDesc" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Delivery Date</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DeliveryDate" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Date Ordered</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="DateOrdered" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Site</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Site" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Time</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Time" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Time Room is Available</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl1" runat="server" DataField="TimeRoomAvailable" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Time Room to be Cleared</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl ID="DynamicControl2" runat="server" DataField="TimeCleared" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Location</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="Location" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Additional Information</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="AdditionalInfo" Mode="ReadOnly" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Item Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="ItemCosts" DataField="ItemCosts" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Additional Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="AdditionalCosts" DataField="AdditionalCosts" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Total Costs</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" ID="TotalCosts" DataField="TotalCosts" Mode="Edit"  /></td>
                </tr>                    

                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">More Information Required</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="MoreInformationRequired" Mode="Edit" UIHint="MultilineText" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Reason Rejected</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ReasonRejected" Mode="Edit" UIHint="MultilineText" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Order Progress</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="OrderProgress" Mode="Edit" UIHint="OrderProgressDropDown" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="td">
                    <td class="DDLightHeader">Imported Into Dream</td>
                    <td><asp:DynamicControl runat="server" DataField="ImportedIntoDream" Mode="Edit" /></td>
                </tr>

                    <tr class="td">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DynamicEntity ID="DynamicEntity3" runat="server" Mode="Insert" />
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton7" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:FormView>
```

I'd like to be able to email the user, based on the email address in the formview, when I click update.

I have amended FormView1_Updated in the code behind as follows:

```
  protected void FormView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, FormViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = e.Keys["OrderNo"].ToString();


        // I have tried this
        //string email = FormView1.FindControl("EmailAddress").ToString();

        //I have also tried this
        //DynamicControl emailadd = ((DynamicControl)FormView1.FindControl("Email"));
        //string email = emailadd.ToString();

        GridView1.DataBind();
        MailMessage objMail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        objMail.To.Add(email);
        objMail.From = new MailAddress("xxxx@xxxxxxx.xx.xx");
        objMail.Subject = "Catering Request";
        objMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        objMail.Body = "<html><body>" +
                    "<p><font face='Verdana' color='#000080' font size='2'>Your catering request, order number " + id + " has been updated by catering. Please view the " +
                    "<a href='http://dev-catering.bathspa.ac.uk/'>Catering Request System</a> for the details.</font></p>";

        smtpClient.Port = xxxx;
        smtpClient.Host = "xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com";

        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        //SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.xx.xx");
        smtpClient.Credentials = nc;
        smtpClient.Send(objMail);
    }
```

If I type an email address straight into the objMail.To.Add(email) field this works fine. My problem is that I cannot capture the value of the email address in the FormView. I keep getting a null error. Has the value of the email address already been destroyed before 'ItemUpdated' is called.

Or am I not finding the value am I just finding the control. If so how do I find the value of the dynamically created control.

Many thanks
Claire

Comment: Have you tried using HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Email"] ?

Comment: Hi Yevgeniy Thanks for your help. I have tried this and it's giving me the error Value cannot be null. It not able to capture that value. I don't know if it's because I'm coding it incorrectly or if it's not able to capture this value at this point.

Comment: Try following DynamicControl emailadd = ((DynamicControl)FormView1.FindControl("Email"));
var value = ((TextBox)emailadd.FieldTemplate.DataControl).Text